# Quicktabs not looking like tabs

Tags: theming

I use quicktabs on D8. When choosing the formater "quicktabs" the tabs do not look like tabs at all, they are just shown as normal links. They have no outlines and so are hardly recognizable as tabs at all. Should they not look like the "normal drupal tabs"? (When I choose to show the tab title, it is also not formated, just plain text, I guess it should be formatted as a header?)

I tried different themes, does not make a change, of course the site looks different, but the tabs still have no outlines. Currently I use Bootstrap default theme.

I am quite new to drupal, just building the site structures now, not having any idea of theming yet. I was already searching a lot, no clues, and all pictures I find of quicktabs on D8 look like tabs, not like the "linklist" I see.

Any hints appreciated :) I am absolutely willing to read / learn more, so if anyone could tell me, where to find more information, that would be great!

(EDIT)
Looks like Quicktabs in D8 are causing several problems. Suddenly all context filters are no longer working for views inside quicktabs (they are working fine outside). And when I add a new quicktabs instance I have to clear the cache to make it show as an available block in the block layout page. Looks like I have to find a layout without tabs... :/

Is anyone using Quicktabs in D8 working as expected?

Comment: Nobody using Quicktabs in D8? :/

Answer (score 0):

[image]Did you try changing tab style? I haven't tried Drupal 8. But you can select no style option in tab style for Drupal 7. Which does not apply any CSS to tabs.

Comment: As I am using a german version of Drupal 8 I am not shure if we are talking about the same thing. There is an option to choose the "formater" (?), I can choose "accordion" / "quicktabs" / "jquery ui". The other two options seem to work, but they look strange (like a different theme or just not at all fitting the rest of the theming).

There is no such thing as a "no style" option on the quicktabs page... Can I change the "tab style" somewhere else?

Comment: When you select quicktabs in formatter, it will show up another dropdown to select style for your quicktab. Have attached a screenshot with my answer above.

Comment: There is no such second dropdown menu in my quicktabs, I think this is a specific problem with quicktabs in D8.